# pam cluster visualization from dissimilarity matrix

Tags: clustering

I'd like to generate cluster graphs based on pam output from the cluster package using `fviz_cluster()` from the factoextra package however, I cannot get `fviz_cluster()` to generate a plot when I feed it a pam object that was created from a dissimilarity matrix. Using the actual variable matrix works, but not a dissimilarity matrix. Is there a way to pass `fviz_cluster()` the variable coordinates to get it to plot the clusters?

I want to use a dissimilarity or distance matrix in pam rather than a variable matrix because I need to calculate my distances using correlations instead of euclidean distances.

```
**Sample code:**

library(cluster)

library(factoextra)

df <- USArrests

df <- scale(na.omit(df))

dist.matrix <- get_dist(df, method = "spearman")

pamx <- pam(dist.matrix, 2, diss="true")

fviz_cluster(pamx)


**ERROR CODE:**
Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have identified the problem and come up with a fix. When you call the `pam()`  function with a dissimilarity matrix as an argument the resulting pam object cannot save the original variable data, this is because we have only provided it with the derived distances. `fviz_cluster()` needs the original data to apply PCA and project the results onto 2D plane.

We can fix the "missing" data problem by simply setting data array in the pam object to the original data and then call `fviz_cluster()` on the newly modified pam object.

`pamx$data <- df`

`fviz_cluster(pamx)`

This solution has worked for me. Unfortunately, I am unable to determine whether the PCA projection is useful/informative when clustering is based on correlation distances instead of euclidean distances.